# Can't set state in js react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setstate

Getting error while trying to `setState` in React Native.

#### Code

```
import React from "react";
import { TextInput, Text, View, Button, Alert } from "react-native";

const UselessTextInput = () => {
  state = { currentDate: "" };

  const setCurentDate = (val) => {
    this.setState({currentDate : val});
  };

  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <View>
      <Text
        style={{
          alignSelf: "center",
          marginTop: 60,
          fontWeight: "bold",
          fontSize: "25",
        }}
      >
        BirthReminder
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 15, fontSize: 15 }}>
        Enter your friend's birthdate, please
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        clearTextOnFocus={true}
        style={{
          height: 40,
          borderColor: "gray",
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop: 20,
          width: 250,
          alignSelf: "center",
        }}
        onChangeText={(value) => setCurentDate(value)}
        value={value}
      />
      <Button title="Add to list"></Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default UselessTextInput;
```

#### Error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.setState')

Comment: you should post the code in the post instead of in a gist

Comment: Functional components use the `useState` hook to use state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### useState Hook

Functional components don't have access to `setState` method but [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.

useState hook works by defining the name of value, e.g. `foo` followed by it's setter. It's a convention to name the setter with the same name as that of value with ***set*** prefix, i.e. `setFoo`

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState('hi');
// pass the initial value here -^^-
```

#### Solution

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const Component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return <TextInput value={value} onChangeText={setValue} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a bit mixed up

replace this as this is the syntax if you use Class component

```
  state = { currentDate: "" };
  const setCurentDate = (val) => {
    this.setState({currentDate : val});
  };
```

with:

```
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState();
  const setCurentDate = (val) => {
    setDate(val);
  };
```

and have a look at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` isn't allowed in functional component. Try to use `React.useState` for `currentDate`

```js
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = React.useState("");

...

const setCurentDate = (val) => {
    setCurrentDate(val);
};
```